# Spring Boot additional properties

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot for creating microservices. By default it uses `application.properties` for configurations. But I have a requirement to use another property file which is outside of jar file. I tried following options in eclipse JVM arguments while running `bootRun` from Gradle but still it didn't work.

```
-Dspring.config.location=c:/another.properties  
-Dspring.config.additional-location=c:/another.properties
-Dspring.config.import=c:/another.properties
```

I also tried adding the above properties inside application.properties but still `@Value` annotation added in controller class which refers a property from `c:/another.properties` is not getting injected.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

The `spring.config.additional-location`  should be a folder and the value should end with `/`

From the documentation:

> You can provide default values for your application in application.properties (or whatever other basename you choose with spring.config.name) in one of the default locations. These default values can then be overridden at runtime with a different file located in one of the custom locations.

REF: [24.3 Application Property Files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)